# Unable to cast object of type ,Drawing Item

Tags: c#, winforms

How to fix problem follow :

when I drawItem, then get message error: 
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[mypro.InfoDialog+Mycontact]' to type 'Mycontact'."

C# code at line number:

```
public class Mycontact
{
        public string P_DISPLAY_NAME    { get; set; }
        public string P_AVAILABILITY    { get; set; }
        public string P_AVATAR_IMAGE    { get; set; }
}

Mycontact fbContact;

private void AddDataToList()
{
    var fbList = new List<Mycontact>();
    foreach (dynamic item in result.data)
    {
        fbContact = new Mycontact() { P_DISPLAY_NAME = (string)item["name"], P_AVAILABILITY = (string)item["online_presence"]};
        fbList.Add(fbContact);
        listBox1.Items.Add(fbList);
    }
}


private int mouseIndex = -1;


private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Index == -1) return;

    line number:
    Mycontact contact = (Mycontact)listBox1.Items[e.Index];

    Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
        if (e.Index > -1)
        {
            // Drawing the frame
            if (e.Index == mouseIndex)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.HotTrack, e.Bounds);
                textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
                    textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
                }else{
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
                }
                // Drawing the text
                e.Graphics.DrawString(contact.P_DISPLAY_NAME, e.Font, textBrush,    e.Bounds.Left + 20, e.Bounds.Top);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You're adding the entire fbList to the control in each iteration of your loop, this doesn't look quite right to me. Why not just add the MyContact instance to the listbox directly?

Answer (score 4):

It seems the whole listed is added to listbox1 instead of a single item (listBox1.Items.Add(fbList))

Shouldn't it be:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(fbContact);
```

Alternatively, you could set listBox1.DataSource = fbList after the loop

Comment: Yes, I can cast , no error more

what the different between ListBox1.Items.Add(value) and listBox1.DataSource = value?

Comment: with the ListBox1.Items.Add(value) you add the value to an internal item collection of the listbox. Possibly to already existing items. By using datasource you bind the listbox to the list you already created. Also in this case, because no begin/endupdate are used for the listbox, there could be a performance gain because the ui doesn't try to update itself per item.

Comment: So, when I used DataSource, Is there events to update data in listbox or not when Drawing?

I mean that, Example when they change their status online or offline, is their event changed or fixed

Comment: Not for a normal list such as used for fblist, because a List<> doesn't implement a listchanged events interface, but if you would make it a BindingList<Mycontact> instead and assign it as a datasource, the listbox would listen to the changes. However, out of the box this works for added deleted items only. For itemchanged events you should have MyContact implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise a changed event whenever a change is made that should update your UI (or any other listeners)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the full list to the listbox as a single item:

`listBox1.Items.Add(fbList);`

So the line

`(Mycontact)listBox1.Items[e.Index];`

Returns a list of MyContact objects instead of a single MyContact object.

So to fix it you could just add contact per contact to the list like this

`listBox1.Items.Add(fbContact);`

Comment: I would like to ask you one question, I want to draw Image from url like: http://skk/image/187285_522637640_1778797875_q.jpg",

I used to draw Image in byte and C# code

Image avatarContact;

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(contact.P_AVATAR_IMAGE);
avatarContact = Image.FromStream(stream);
e.Graphics.DrawImage(avatarContact, e.Bounds.Left + 4, e.Bounds.Top + 5, 32, 32);

- What type of Stream I should use for string image?